# How to redirect in php project using .htaccess file (redirect url without slash to url with slash using 301 redirect)

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect the urls in PHP as following using .htaccess file. 
https://beld.onepa/bood-uddevalla  ->   https://beld.onepa/bood-uddevalla/  
https://beld.onempa/buten-vbras/ ->  https://beld.onempa/buten-vbras 
How can I describe command in .htaccess

Comment: AFAIK, .htaccess is something used in Apache. If you mean Apache, then add that tag and remove some of the others. Maybe all of them, since they don't seem relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Redirect 301 /old/page /new/page
```

or

```
Redirect 302 /old/page /new/page
```

Keep in mind:

A 301 redirect is a status code that tells search engines and users the page has permanently moved.

A 302 redirect is a temporary change that redirects both users and search engines to the desired new location for a limited amount of time, until the redirect is removed.